# ROR + Increase Time Stamp By One Hour

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

Here, My timestamps code for Ruby is

```
#{Time.now.utc.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(Time.now.day)}%Y%R")}".
```

Now I want to increase my hour by one. So how it can be possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can add one hour and then format them to your previous format:

```
(Time.now+1.hour).utc.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(Time.now.day)}%Y%R")
```

Comment: A nicer way of writing that would be: `1.hour.from_now.utc.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(Time.now.day)}%Y%R")`. It could also be made considerably more readable by extracting the strftime logic to `Time::DATE_FORMATS`, then you could use `.to_s(:format_name)`